# ResponsiveSlides.js slideshow not being called

Tags: javascript, responsive-slides

I am trying to add a [responsiveSlides.js](https://github.com/viljamis/ResponsiveSlides.js) slideshow to a website I am working on ([here](http://www.stonewatercc.com/index.php/jstest)), but the method doesn't seem to be being called.  I'm guessing it is just a syntax error, but I can't for the life of me find it.

In the head of the site, I have

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{stylesheet=home/responsiveslides}" />

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://stonewatercc.com/js/responsiveslides.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
    $('#slider1').responsiveSlides();
  });
</script>
```

and the code containing the images for the slideshow (in the body) is

```
<ul class="rslides" id="slider1">
    <li><img src="{site_url}images/stonewatercc/slider/stonewater_pics01.jpg" alt=""></li>
    <li><img src="{site_url}images/stonewatercc/slider/stonewater_pics02.jpg" alt=""></li>
    <li><img src="{site_url}images/stonewatercc/slider/stonewater_pics03.jpg" alt=""></li>
</ul>
```

I can put an alert before the line '$('slider1').responsiveSlides();', but if I put it after that line, it doesn't get called.  I can type either url into the browser to get to the respective .js files.

I would really appreciate help with this since it is driving me mad knowing that it is probably something quite simple that I am just missing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call it, you should use this:

```
(function ($) {
  $('#slider1').responsiveSlides();
}(jQuery));
```

This namespaces jQuery to this particular function, which will ensure you don't have any conflicting libraries, such as Prototype which I see is loaded.

To help with trouble shooting an issue of this nature you should first make sure you have jQuery by typing `jQuery` in your console.  In the case of your site, it is there:

[image]

Next, try to get the object from the console: `$('#slider1')`.  In doing so, you can see that it returns `null`:

[image]

Obviously there is something wrong because we can see `id="slider1"` by viewing source.

The final step I took was to make sure it was correct (I have never seen it `$(function()...`), so I typed directly into the console: `(function($) { $('#slider1').responsiveSlides() }(jQuery))` and voila, your slideshow started.

Comment: First, thanks for the help, this is driving me nuts.  When I put what you did into the console ((function($) { $('#slider1').responsiveSlides() }(jQuery))), the slideshow started, just like it did for you.  Unfortunately, when I added (jQuery) into the actual code in the header, the slideshow didn't start.  I also tried switching the "function($)" with "$(window).load(function()", but that also didn't work.  I can put an alert() as the first line after function() and have the alert work, so both lines work to start the code being read.

Comment: Also, if you type $('slider1') into the console, it returns the html code contained within <ul name="rslides" id="slider1"></ul>.  Unfortunately, taking the "#" out of the code in the head of the site doesn't make the slideshow run, and if you take out the # when entering the function code into the console, it doesn't display an error, but it also doesn't run.

Comment: The JavaScript in your header isn't what I put in the post :) It still contains the namespace issue.  Leave out `$(window).load()` for now, and copy/paste this directly into your header: `(function($) { 
  $('#slider1').responsiveSlides(
   {speed:1000,timeout:5000}
   )
}(jQuery))`

Comment: I'm thinking about the `$(window).load()`...Without getting into responsiveSlides.js actual code, you may need to run this using `window.load()`.

Comment: Currently, the code I'm using in the header is: $(document).load(function($) { $('#slider1').responsiveSlides( {speed:1000,timeout:5000} ); }(jQuery));

Comment: Yes, if you want to use `$(document).load()` it needs to be within the name space; however, it's unnecessary to use `document.load()` when name spacing jQuery this way.  You can use `window.load()` but, again, it needs to be within `(function($) { $(window).load(function() {......`

Comment: Thank you! I was missing the initial (function($) {.  It's working now.